# Modify self-hosted Owin "require SSL"

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, owin, self-hosting

Our Android Chrome users are facing this message when hit self hosted Owin application:[image]

On IIS Environment, the way to solve this, is setting "Require SSL" to ignore, like below:

[image]

Is there any configuration on Owin to disable Android Chrome messages?

Tks

Answer (score 3):

Those IIS settings don't quite apply to self-host.

1. On the command line verify that `netsh http show ssl` shows `Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled` for your endpoint.
2. Aside from the netsh setting, client certificates in selfhost are requested lazily. E.g. When you ask if there is a client cert for the request it will dynamically request one from the client. You just have to be careful not to request one. See the `ssl.` keys here: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OWIN%20Keys. If you're using WebApi via OWIN see this code: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/OwinHttpRequestContext.cs

Comment: 1. Ok, it is working.

2. I'm using WebApi Owin but I can't understand your tip. Could you be more especific? I can't understand how to use the code.

Comment: I just mean that you should verify that the ClientCertificate is never accessed in the application or else it will dynamically request one from the client.

Comment: In my code I don't access ClientCertificate. I'm just using Owin with SSL. I believe the Owin that access the ClientCertificate, is there some configuration to ignore this verify ClientCertificate?